# Adding my own tags inside HTML blocks in Perl

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing

Is there a way to receive a html page, look for  blocks and enclose text with my own characters?

For example given the following html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Appleseed Farm</title>
</html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td><img src="blah/blah.jpg"></td> 
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>Some random text</div>
<p>Random image of the day: <img src="random.jpg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Becomes the following with my '@' tag around text:

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>@Appleseed Farm@</title>
</html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Col1@</td>
        <td>@Col2@</td>
        <td><img src="blah/blah.jpg"></td> 
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>@Some random text@</div>
<p>@Random image of the day:@ <img src="random.jpg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. In fact, there are several. But asking for software-recommendations is unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow. You will have to get started on this yourself, and if you run into trouble we're happy to provide assistance. If I were you, I'd start searching for something like how to replace text nodes in HTML, or parsing XML. Looking for HTML and XML on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org) should already give you a good starting point.

Comment: What @simbabque says is good advice; search for it, both in CPAN and (the many) existing SO posts.  To give you at least something specific, I use [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~kentnl/HTML-Tree-5.07/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) to parse and process HTML -- but there is a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad question. I did figure it out after going through the HTML::Element page.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use feature ':5.10';

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(\*DATA);
$root->elementify;

for my $e ($root->look_down (
    sub {
      my $tag = $_[0]->tag();
      grep( /^$tag$/, qw(td div p title span) ) 
      }
  ))
{
    #Do an in-place replacement
    foreach my $item_r ($e->content_refs_list) {
        next if ref $$item_r;
        $$item_r =~ s/^(.+)$/\@$1\@/g;
    }
}

say $root->as_HTML (undef, "  ", {});

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
    <title>Appleseed Farm</title>
</html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td><img src="blah/blah.jpg">Col 3</td> 
        <td>cat</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>Some random text</div>
<p>Random image of the day: <img src="random.jpg"></p>
</body>
```